# Looping by date instead of index in each_with_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to sort by two key columns whilst doing a each_with_index loop. The first sorting option `:selection_id` works fine, but the order of the collection loop seems to ignore the `assessments.date` order.

My date is in milliseconds. Could this be the issue?

**Loop**

```
<% unless data.progressions.blank? %>
    <% data.progressions.order('selection_id, assessments.date ASC').in_groups_of(7)[i].each_with_index do |e, index| %>
    <% if index == 0 %>
      <%= e.selection.name rescue 0 %>
    <% end %>
    <%= Time.at(e.assessment.date/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") rescue 0 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So whats happen is that it displays something like this.

```
|name 1|     0    |0|0|0|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|23/01/2018|

|name 2|28/02/2018|0|0|0|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|21/01/2018|
```

Which isn't displaying the dates in order, and in some cases it adds null records in-between.

I'm expecting to get:

```
|name 1|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|23/01/2018|     0    |0|0|0|

|name 2|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|21/01/2018|28/02/2018|0|0|0|
```

Comment: Am i able to order by association in the loop call?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the thing you actually want is to have the records grouped by :selection_id and then ordered by `assessments.date` within each group. I think the problem is that by using `order` for both those attributes, you are probably mixing different selections within each of those groups, but you don't notice it because you only show the selection name for the first index.

I would suggest you to solve it by doing something like this.

```
<% if (selections = data.progressions.order("assessments.date  ASC").group_by(&:selection)).any? %>
  <% selections.each_pair do |selection, collections| %>
    <%= selection.name %>
    <% collections.each do |e| %>
      <%= Time.at(e.assessment.date/1000).strftime("%d/%m/%Y") rescue 0 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What happens here is that all records are first ordered by the `assessments.date`, but then called `group_by(&:selection)` will create a Hash object where the keys are each unique `:selection` and the values will by all the `progressions` that belong to the selection. For example:

```
{ #<Selection id=1 ...> => [ #<Progression id=2 ...>, #<Progression id=3 ...> ],
  #<Selection id=4 ...> => [ #<Progression id=5 ...> ]
}
```

So by using the method `each_pair` we can loop through the selections first and then do the collections in a sub loop.

As a last note, this procedure can be improved performance wise by using `data.progressions.includes(:selection, :assessment)`, but I wouldn't worry about that until you have the base functionality working properly.

I hope I haven't made things too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally use two orders like this, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Your second order will indeed overwrite the first, because that's how it works (so you can rescope default sort orders).

Normally you'd use one `order` using both fields eg

```
order("selection_id ASC, assessments.dat ASC")
```

or similar... Is that what you're trying to do?

Here's some more examples of using order: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Thanks for your reply Taryn. I've tried the above, and still seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Cool - so now I need t know what it is that you're *trying* to do with your two orderings. What error do you observe? what did you expect instead?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but I have added some text in which it displays the results.

Comment: Ok by "errors" I also meant "how do you know that it didn't work" ;) but yeah - what you showed counts. I agree with the other answer... that your html implies that each row contains one selection_id... but the selections are actually spanning rows. The dates *are* in ascending order. But the relevant ones are wrapping around the lines eg you are expecting: `|name 1|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|23/01/2018|28/02/2018` but getting `|name 1|02/01/2018|15/01/2018|23/01/2018|
|name 2|28/02/2018`

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I've updated the question with what i'm expecting to get.

Comment: Yep - so the problem is exactly what the other person suggests - and you need to use group-by selection, not order-by.